# Keep an element visible, but prevent from overflowing its parent?

Tags: html, css, position, background-image, css-position

Is there a way to make an element not contribute to parent overflow, but keep it visible? Let me clarify

There is a watermark-like logo to be applied to a page in the manner below. It is supposed to be positioned partly outside the main content (dashed blue line)

I'm not aware of the option to set an element background in such a manner that it would persist as the browser window is resized horizontally, so I've just added a `<div>` with the logo as its background and `position:absolute` with the necessary offset relative to main content container.

Previously, the page would not get a horizontal scrollbar as long as the browser was wider than `W1`. Now, *with an additional "watermark" element added outside of the main content box*, the scrollbar would appear whenever the browser is narrower than `W2`

Is there something obvious I'm missing? A background setting, or possibly a neat margin workaround/

[image: mockup]

### Update:

I've added a [rough jsfiddle to illustrate the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/spsww/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, just because you nested the "watermark" div and positioned it absolutely doesn't make it outside of the document. If you put it outside of the document, the page will scroll (as you see).

To me, the first solution I think of is to move the watermark outside of the "content" div and apply the watermark to its parent container. I'm guessing you haven't done that because you need it to be relative to the "content" div, but it's something to try.

Also, the reason it scrolls is because the document has been overflow. The quick fix, yet not recommended, is to use "overflow-x: hidden;" on the parent container of the "content" div.

It's harder to give you a solution since you've stripped the rest of your HTML, and some "fixes" may not be as applicable if your structure is complicated in certain ways.

Comment: I was thinking of `overflow-x:hidden`, however I don't want to encounter a scenario where the browser is resized to less than `W1` and the main content is cropped. I imagine I could somewhat try addressing this by using a media query or something.

Comment: Of course, that's why I thought it probably wasn't the right solution, but a quick fix instead. So in your example, is W2 the <body> element (or the main parent)? If your HTML was a little more complex like with more elements between the watermark and the main parent, depending on fixed or relative widths, you could set it up in a way that overflow-x isn't a bad idea, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the width of your elements is greater than the actual "width" it includes padding & margins, if you have padding on your div reduce the "width" by the equivalent amount.

does that make sense? if you post the actual css & html it might be easier to give you a more detailed answer

additionally could you not assign the image as the background of the actual body element and set it to centered?

I've had a play with the code and come up with a possible solution for you.

set

```
body{overflow-x:hidden;}
```

then add

```
@media all and (max-width: 400px)
{
 body{overflow-x:auto;   }
}
```

as soon as your screen is smaller than 400px (the width of the div) your overflow:hidden will be overridden and you'll be given you scroll bars.

at this point you may also want to reduce the width of your watermark.

Comment: This is not a padding issue (i.e. anything contributing to the width has been accounted for). I've added a jsfiddle - not actual css&html but something sufficient to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I just realised you've commented pretty much the same thing down below - sorry didn't see the comment

Comment: np, but +1 for suggesting the width of the watermark be reduced!